# How to create ear using using another project war through multi module approach

Tags: maven

I have one maven project(lets say Proj1) which creates a war file. I want to create a parent project(lets day Proj2) which will create an .ear using the war project. So that when I build Proj2, it should build the war from Proj1 and then use it to create .ear

Comment: There is an example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276973/integrate-spring-boot-in-an-ear-project/43277578#43277578)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is your project to be structured this way:

```
  Parent project (packaged as pom)
    -->Child-EAR project (packaged as EAR)
    -->Child-WAR project (packaged as WAR)
```

Each project should have a pom file, parent project should include the child projects as its module. The child project should include the parent module. Please see this link: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/04/java-ee7-and-maven-project-for-newbies-part-1-a-simple-maven-project-structure-the-parent-pom.html it explains in detail.