# Unable to deploy Spring boot 2.1.4 application to WAS 9

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, websphere

I am trying to deploy a spring boot 2.1.4 application on WAS 9 using WAS admin console, but I get this error

> The EAR file could be corrupt and/or incomplete. Make sure that the
>   application is at a compatible Java(TM) Platform, Enterprise Edition
>   (Java EE) level for the current version of WebSphere(R) Application
>   Server.
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ManifestException:
>   IWAE0015E An IOException occurred reading the manifest in archive:
>   WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar [Root exception is
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ManifestException:
>   IWAE0015E An IOException occurred reading the manifest in archive:
>   WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar]

WAS info:

> Name: IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment
>   Version:9.0.0.6

Java version of the WAS:

> Name: IBM SDK, Java Technology Edition, Version 8 Version: 8.0.5.7

Spring Boot app's pom xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <parent>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
         <relativePath/> 
     </parent>
     <groupId>com.ibm.csc.services.pnmapping</groupId>
     <artifactId>IBMPN2SupplierMapping</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>war</packaging>
     <name>IBMPN2SupplierMapping</name>
     <description>Spring Boot project</description>

     <properties>
         <java.version>1.8</java.version>
     </properties>

     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
     <dependency>
     <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
     <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
         <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
     </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>

         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis.spring.boot/mybatis-spring-boot-starter -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
             <version>1.3.1</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
             <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
             <version>9.7</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
             <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
             <version>9.7</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
         </dependency>
     </dependencies>

     <build>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             </plugin>
         </plugins>
     </build>

 </project>
```

Comment: The error says you're deploying an ear, but you are making a war from spring.

Comment: take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276973/integrate-spring-boot-in-an-ear-project/43277578#43277578)

Comment: Can you display the whole stack trace of the error?   Can you display /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF of WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar?